# iPhone parsing url for GET params

Tags: iphone, string

I have an string which is got from parsing an xml site.

```
http://www.arijasoft.com/givemesomthing.php?a=3434&amp;b=435edsf&amp;c=500
```

I want to have an NSString function that will be able to parse the value of c.
Is there a default function or do i have to write it manually.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use Regular expression via RegExKit Lite:
http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/

Or you could separate the string into components (which is less nice):

```
NSString *url=@"http://www.arijasoft.com/givemesomthing.php?a=3434&b=435edsf&c=500";
NSArray *comp1 = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];
NSString *query = [comp1 lastObject];
NSArray *queryElements = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
for (NSString *element in queryElements) {
    NSArray *keyVal = [element componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    if (keyVal.count > 0) {
       NSString *variableKey = [keyVal objectAtIndex:0];
       NSString *value = (keyVal.count == 2) ? [keyVal lastObject] : nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. This is what i am trying to use.

Comment: this works until parameter value contains the '=' char, like LptOaQ==  
For that use instead `NSString *value = [element substringFromIndex:[element rangeOfString:@"="].location+1];  
    NSString *variableKey = [element substringToIndex:[element rangeOfString:@"="].location];`

Comment: NSString *query = [url query];  is a bit cleaner to use then separating by "?" ... if the lastObject contains a fragment ("#fragment"), the last object when separating by "&" wouldn't be what you're expecting.

Answer (score 6):

I made a class that does this parsing for you using an `NSScanner`, as an answer to the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225814/nsurl-pull-out-a-single-value-for-a-key-in-a-parameter-string/2226267#2226267) a few days ago. You might find it useful.

You can easily use it like:

```
    URLParser *parser = [[[URLParser alloc] initWithURLString:@"http://www.arijasoft.com/givemesomthing.php?a=3434&b=435edsf&c=500"] autorelease];
    NSString *c = [parser valueForVariable:@"c"];   //c=500
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.arijasoft.com/givemesomthing.php?a=3434&b=435edsf&c=500"];
NSMutableString *parameterString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"{%@;}",[url parameterString]];
[parameterString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@";"];
// Convert string into Dictionary
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSString *error;    
NSDictionary *paramDict = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:[parameterString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutabilityOption: NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&error];

// Now take the parameter you want
NSString *value = [paramDict valueForKey:@"c"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the native iOS approach using `NSURLComponents` and `NSURLQueryItem` classes:

```
NSString *theURLString = @"http://www.arijasoft.com/givemesomthing.php?a=3434&b=435edsf&c=500";    
NSArray<NSURLQueryItem *> *theQueryItemsArray = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:theURLString].queryItems;
for (NSURLQueryItem *theQueryItem in theQueryItemsArray)
{
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", theQueryItem.name, theQueryItem.value);
}
```