# How can I extract parameters from a non-standard URL NSString object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm diving into iOS development and I have a custom URL scheme for my iPhone app that looks like `myApp://?q=200`.  I have the following code to get the query parameter...

```
NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
NSString *query = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"myApp://?q=" withString:@""];
```

...but I'd like to make it a bit more future-proof in the event that I add more parameters.  How can I extract the "q" parameter in a safer way?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: Check this our http://stackoverflow.com/a/2243853/468724

Answer (score 2):

You can split the query returned from the URL by `&` and `=` and put them in a dictionary.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myApp://?q=200"];


NSArray *query = [[url query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[query count]];
for(NSString *parameter in query)
{
    NSArray *kv = [parameter componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    [parameters setObject:[kv count] > 1 ? [[kv objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] : [NSNull null]
               forKey:[[kv objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];
}

NSLog(@"Parameters: %@", parameters);
NSLog(@"q = %@", [parameters objectForKey:@"q"]);
```

In this example if there is no value for the parameter I just set it to `NSNull`. This means you would either need to check for `NSNull` or change the logic to skip keys with values or set them to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

This from the top of my head could work but doesnt yet include error checking the input

```
-(NSDictionary*) parameterDictionaryFromString: (NSURL*) url {
//input can be something like: "myApp://?q=one&q2=two&q3=three"
NSString *requestString = [url query];

//now we have q=one&q2=two&q3=three

NSArray *requests = [requestString componentsSeparatedByString: @"&"];

NSMutableDictionary *resultDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSString *singleParameter in requests) {
    NSArray *keyValuePair = [singleParameter componentsSeparatedByString: @"="];
    [resultDictionary setObject: [keyValuePair objectAtIndex: 1] forKey: [keyValuePair objectAtIndex: 0]];
}
NSURL *u = [NSURL URLWithString: @"myApp://something?q=1&check=yes"];
NSLog(@"paramStr = %@", [u parameterString]);

return [resultDictionary copy];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. Break the Query String by Distinct Separator,
2. Assure Valued Content provided at index:1 (The right-hand side of the query string break)
3. In valued content then use downstream, or set to upstream variable.

---

```
//Your Example:
//@"myApp://?q=200"

//Break:
NSArray *queryParts = [urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"?q="];

//Assure Content:
if ([[array objectAtIndex:1] length]>0) {

    //Setter:
    NSString *queryString = [array objectAtIndex:1];

    //... Use away...
}
```

The key is to leverage the NSArray class over StringReplace.