# extract parameter from UIWebView NSURLRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an url " http://www.website.com/?id=123&val1=abc&val2=x "

I would like to get the value for the parameters such as "id" and "val2" how do I do that?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225814/nsurl-pull-out-a-single-value-for-a-key-in-a-parameter-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSURL pull out a single value for a key in a parameter string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225814/nsurl-pull-out-a-single-value-for-a-key-in-a-parameter-string)