# Objective-C/iPhone - String replacing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, replace, nsstring

How would I go about removing the "&expires_in=87131" within the following `NSString`:

Obviously the value 87131 may change in the future and it's always the last part of the string as well.

```
NSString *accessToken = @"136369349714439%7C2.nNIKZW8Z7Yw_aaaffqKv7lVFYJg__.86400.1301824800-705896566%7Cp-z9A68pJqTDNjEMj0TrHogc2bw&expires_in=87131";
NSString *newStr = [accessToken stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Is it always the last part of the string?

Comment: Correct, it's always the last part of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string is guaranteed to only have one ampersand in it:

```
NSArray *components = [accessToken componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
accessToken = [components objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I think this will do, I'm pretty certain it will be the first ampersand before that particular string value.

Comment: If not, consider componentsSeparatedByString:@"&expires_in" instead, in case you have a stray & sign in the actual access token (don't believe it can happen but you never know).

Comment: Added Kalle's suggestion, thanks for all your help guys. Much much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For 'fixing the %7C characters' see NSString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding

Comment: It's not easy actually with the default libraries. A regular expression would be error-prone. Your best bet is to decompose the URL into parameters, remove the one you don't want, then rebuild the URL. You really want a URL parser. There's discussion of one here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225814/nsurl-pull-out-a-single-value-for-a-key-in-a-parameter-string