# Better way of getting a certain value from a URL

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsurl

I have the following URL from which I want to extract the id parameter:

> assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id= ***123456789*** &ext=JPG

I wonder if there is a better way to figure out the value for `id` than this:

```
NSString *id = [[[[def.url.query componentsSeparatedByString:@"id="] 
                          lastObject]
                         componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"] 
                        objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Did you try regular expressions?

Comment: I did not. So far I have never used regular expressions with Objective-C

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSURL pull out a single value for a key in a parameter string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225814/nsurl-pull-out-a-single-value-for-a-key-in-a-parameter-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case something along these lines would probably work (somewhat simplified, but working):

```
NSString *string = @"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=123456789&ext=JPG";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"id=([^&]+)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches objectAtIndex:0];
NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:1];

NSString *idSting = [string substringWithRange:range];
NSLog(@"%@", idSting);
```

Comment: +1 I tried this in Xcode and it worked nicely. It is a bit verbose but not as hacky as my approach, which would not work if the second parameter would wan't there.