# NSScanner unrecognized selector on scanUpToString

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6, nsscanner

I use the [URL parser class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225814/nsurl-pull-out-a-single-value-for-a-key-in-a-parameter-string) from Dimitris but i encounter a problem when init object trought `initWithURLString`:

```
- (id) initWithURLString:(NSString *)url{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        NSString *string = url;
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
        [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"&?"]];
        NSString *tempString;
        NSMutableArray *vars = [NSMutableArray new];
        //ignore the beginning of the string and skip to the vars
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"?" intoString:nil];
        while ([scanner scanUpToString:@"&" intoString:&tempString]) {
            [vars addObject:[tempString copy]];
        }
        self.variables = vars;
    }
    return self;
}
```

On line `[scanner scanUpToString:@"?" intoString:nil];` i get an error:

> [NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f8c2050

How is it possible?

EDIT: maybe you want to know how i call URLParser:

```
URLParser *urlParser = [[URLParser alloc]initWithURLString:[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]];
```

UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL value is : assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=8D2F0449-11A3-4962-9D60-C446831645D7&ext=PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass a NSURL to initWithURLString, but you should use it with NSString like this:

```
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]];
URLParser *parser = [[[URLParser alloc] initWithURLString:urlString] autorelease];
```

Comment: Thanks! I use absoluteString to cast my NSURL to NSString.