# NSString have some attribute values With & symbol how to get that attribute values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have received response from the server.

I have stored that values in one string.

But my problem is in that string have some attribute values with & symbol its not an xml structure, so how can I get that attribute values in that string.

This is i am getting response from server.  [Newlines have been added for clarity, it was all run together in one line -- editor]

```
&currency_code=USD
&currency_symbol$
&email_id=good@good.com
&usertypecode=ROBT
&id=fcscdj
&player_level=1
&player_isblocked=false
&lang=en
&respond=true
&flylogin=false
&str=PageEnd
&user_balance=100000394.90
&user_bonus_balance=0.00
&user_id=e4567
```

How can I get this values and show in label example currency code values in need to show in one label like USD in that label.
Like that I need to do all dis `email_id`,`usertypecode`,`player_isblocked`

Please help me out This problem

Comment: Those "attribute values" look like HTTP request query parameters.  Look at the accepted answer of this SO question for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225814/nsurl-pull-out-a-single-value-for-a-key-in-a-parameter-string

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters, looks like the data could be considered analogous to an `NSDictionary`.

You could take this string as an `NSString` and get an `NSArray` by sending the message `componentsSeparatedByString:` with an arg of `@"&"`.

```
NSArray *firstArray = [responseString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
```

Then create an `NSMutableDictionary`

```
NSMutableDictionary *mDict = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity: firstArray.count ];
```

Then use fast enumeration to populate the key value pairs.

```
for ( NSString *aKVP in firstArray) {
    NSArray *tempArray = [aKVP componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    [mDict setValue: tempArray[1] forKey: tempArray[0] ];
}
```

Then you have a data structure you can use. 
You can access the values by key to set button labels or whatever else you want to do.

Other approaches would include things like `NSScanner` or `NSRegularExpression` but this is straight forward and flexible if you need the rest.

Comment: @mttrb  I have one doubt i have getting all values from tempArray  like dis (
    usertypecode,
    ROBT
)
how can i show ROBT only in one label i have getting lot of values like dis in temparray(
    "email_id",
    "test1@test.com"
)
tempArray (
    "user_currency_code",
    USD
)

Comment: Just take the value you want.

Comment: i dont know that how to get that values and show in label i am new for iphone .Please help me out dis problem