# How to decode NSURL in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, decoding

i am NewBie in iOS Development. I want to Decode my NSURL With Pagination Here my Url Like as

```
http://www.janvajevu.com/webservice/categorylist.php?category=%E0%AA%B8%E0%AB%8D%E0%AA%B5%E0%AA%BE%E0%AA%B8%E0%AB%8D%E0%AA%A5%E0%AA%AF&page=0
```

And i Decode this URL Like as

```
NSURL *urls = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.janvajevu.com/webservice/categorylist.php?category=%E0%AA%B8%E0%AB%8D%E0%AA%B5%E0%AA%BE%E0%AA%B8%E0%AB%8D%E0%AA%A5%E0%AA%AF&page=0"];
NSString *urlString = [urls absoluteString];
NSLog(@"UrlString %@",urlString);
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

But it Give me Only 0 Page Url i want to Like as make my url as

```
NSURL *urls=[NSURL URLWithString:@"My Url &page=%d",pagenum];
```

Here i want at place of My Url as Decoding of my Original Url If it is Possible then Please Give me Solution for it.

Comment: Pa6i su karis........

Comment: From where you are getting this URL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSURL pull out a single value for a key in a parameter string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225814/nsurl-pull-out-a-single-value-for-a-key-in-a-parameter-string)

Comment: @Milanpatel Who are you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are doing it in wrong way.
this is the right way

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.janvajevu.com/webservice/categorylist.php?category=%E0%AA%B8%E0%AB%8D%E0%AA%B5%E0%AA%BE%E0%AA%B8%E0%AB%8D%E0%AA%A5%E0%AA%AF&page=";

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",urlString,pageNumber]];
NSLog(@"targetURL is : %@",targetURL);
```

Comment: i think you want `page=%d` in your first line and not `page=0`

Comment: @Fonix But then how i Increase it?

Comment: @Fonix i write my First line like as 
 NSURL *urls = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.janvajevu.com/webservice/categorylist.php?category=%E0%AA%B8%E0%AB%8D%E0%AA%B5%E0%AA%BE%E0%AA%B8%E0%AB%8D%E0%AA%A5%E0%AA%AF&page=%d",pageNums];    as You Call then it Give me Error Here my PageNums is int Variable and it's Initial Value is 0

Comment: @AshishGabani use this as it is. i have append your page number with your url, see updated answer

Comment: @Nitin Yes I Use it and It iS Working Fine thnx Bro.

Comment: @AshishGabani anytime bro. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you..

NSString *str=@"http://www.janvajevu.com/webservice/categorylist.php?category=%E0%AA%B8%E0%AB%8D%E0%AA%B5%E0%AA%BE%E0%AA%B8%E0%AB%8D%E0%AA%A5%E0%AA%AF&page=0";

```
NSString *result =[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *urls = [NSURL URLWithString:result] ;
```